# How can I read from one HBase instance but write to another?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Currently I have two Hbase tables (lets call them `tableA` and `tableB`). Using a single stage MapReduce job the data in `tableA` is read processed and saved to `tableB`.  Currently both tables reside on the same HBase cluster. However, I need to relocate `tableB` to its on cluster.

Is it possible to configure a single stage map reduce job in Hadoop to read and write from separate instances of HBase?

Comment: You can use spark for this type job.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, HBase's [CopyTable MapReduce job](https://hbase.apache.org/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/CopyTable.html) does it by using [`TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob()`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.html#initTableReducerJob(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which allows you to set an alternative quorumAddress in case you need to write to remote clusters:

```
public static void initTableReducerJob(String table, Class<? extends TableReducer> reducer, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job job, Class partitioner, String quorumAddress, String serverClass, String serverImpl)
```

> **quorumAddress** - Distant cluster to write to; default is null for
>   output to the cluster that is designated in hbase-site.xml. Set this
>   String to the zookeeper ensemble of an alternate remote cluster when
>   you would have the reduce write a cluster that is other than the
>   default; e.g. copying tables between clusters, the source would be
>   designated by hbase-site.xml and this param would have the ensemble
>   address of the remote cluster. The format to pass is particular. Pass
>   ::
>   such as server,server2,server3:2181:/hbase.

---

Another option is to implement your own custom reducer to write to the remote table instead of writing to the context. Something similar to this:

```
public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, Result, Text, Text> {

    protected Table remoteTable; 
    protected Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);
        // Clone configuration and provide a new quorum address for the remote cluster
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create(context.getConfiguration());
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","quorum1,quorum2,quorum3");
        connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config); // HBase 0.99+
        //connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(config); // HBase <0.99
        remoteTable = connection.getTable("myTable".getBytes());
        remoteTable.setAutoFlush(false);
        remoteTable.setWriteBufferSize(1024L*1024L*10L); // 10MB buffer
    }

    public void reduce(Text boardKey, Iterable<Result> results, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        /* Write puts to remoteTable */
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.cleanup(context);
        if (remoteTable!=null) {
            remoteTable.flushCommits();
            remoteTable.close();
        }
        if(connection!=null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotta love people who downvotes perfectly valid answers just for fun.

Comment: Thanks for providing an example of a custom reduce